# Copy-item command is throwing Access denied error

Tags: azure-devops

I am using below command from my test01 server from where i want to invoke the copy-item command on the test02 server.. I am facing **access is denied** issue.

test01 is the servername where my sharefolder is there
test02 is the remote machine

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “pass” -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“work”, $password)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item '\test01\new' 'c:\test' -Force -Recurse} -ComputerName "test02" -Credential $Cred
strong text

Comment: Not get your latest information,if the answer is helpful, please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442), just click the option like this . Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your build agent lacks **Admin permission** to perform the action. (`Invoke-Command -ComputerName` requires admin permission...)

Try updating current agent or installing a new agent(suggest creating a new agent pool) with Admin account and then start the agent with Admin account. You can refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550343/run-powershell-or-command-prompt-as-administrator-during-visual-studio-team-serv) for more details.